# How to allow users to add in parameter in api?

Tags: node.js, api, express

How to allow users to add in parameter in api? i.e http://localhost:8080/amk_codes?collada_north=1.361692308&collada_east=103.8527273

I have the following codes:

```
app.get("/amk_codes", async (req, res) => {

const rows = await readamk_codes();

res.send(JSON.stringify(rows))

})


async function readamk_codes() {
try {
const results = await client.query("select collada_north,collada_south,collada_east from amk_codes");
return results.rows;
}
catch(e){
    return [];
}
}
```

Comment: you are posting code on this website for others to read -- you should indent your code in a way that makes it easier for people to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters in url are located in `req.query` object. In your example you can access to **collada_north** and **collada_south** values with `req.query.collada_north` and `req.query.collada_south`.

```
app.get("/amk_codes", async (req, res) => {

    var collada_north = req.query.collada_north
    var collada_south = req.query.collada_south
    const rows = await readamk_codes();

    res.send(JSON.stringify(rows))

})

...
```

Of course you have to check if parameters are present in the request ( they could also be null I think ).